# iOS Text Wrapping

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, uitextview

In the app I am currently developing, I have to implement a screen which allows the user to ask a question. This screen contains a UIImageView next to the UITextView, taking up a portion of the space. It looks like the below image.

[image: Problem]

My question is, how can I wrap the UITextView text around the UIImageView, so that the text won't be in a block, but flowing around the UIImageView?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this, unless your UITextView was a rich text or HTML editor, with the image embedded inside it. Basically what you're asking for is a non-rectangular UITextView. To the best of my knowledge, that is impossible in iOS, unless you were to create something brand new from scratch, which would be extremely complex. I have seen plenty of UILabel-style controls that can **display** HTML-like text, but not **edit** it.

EDIT: this might help: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/01/rich-text-editing-on-ios/

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that's not a trivial issue as the UITextField does not provide any functionality that would be useful here.

However what you could do is to implement your own text view using UITextInput (for text input) and Core Text (for text display) and then define the drawing rectangle for Core Text (you can read more on Core Text [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Overview/Overview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005533-CH3-SW1)) from a custom CGPath that would exclude the images frame.

It does sound a bit complex (insane, perhaps), however as (nearly always) there are open source solutions that already found a solution. The [OmniGroup framework](https://github.com/omnigroup/OmniGroup) contains custom text input controls based on Core Text and UITextInput. They're licensed under MIT License (well, moreless) so you should be just fine.